# What is the GDTCORStorage class and the unarchivedObjectOfClass?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

This is my first time working with Firebase and I use Xcode 9.4.1 plus Swift 4. I used CocoaPods to install Firebase into my project.

These are my code snippets (and errors) below:

```
#pragma mark - GDTCORLifecycleProtocol

- (void)appWillForeground:(GDTCORApplication *)app {
  if (@available(macOS 10.13, iOS 11.0, tvOS 11.0, *)) {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[GDTCORStorage archivePath]];
    if (data) {
      [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[GDTCORStorage class] fromData:data error:&error];
    }
  } else {
#if !TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
    [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[GDTCORStorage archivePath]];
#endif
  }
}
```

For the code snippet above I am getting this error:

```
No known class method for selector 'unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:'
```

Also for this snippet of code:

```
if (@available(macOS 10.13, iOS 11.0, tvOS 11.0, *)) {
      NSError *error;
      NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self
                                           requiringSecureCoding:YES
                                                           error:&error];
      [data writeToFile:[GDTCORStorage archivePath] atomically:YES];
    } else {
#if !TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
      [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self toFile:[GDTCORStorage archivePath]];
#endif
    }
```

I am getting the error:

```
No known class method for selector 'archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:'
```

There doesn't seem to be many resources online about this issue. Except upgrading Xcode, but in my case I can't upgrade my Xcode. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Please use code completion or read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver/2962880-archiveddata) (that's **the** online resource). Swift 3+ methods don't have an `error` parameter, they `throw`.

Comment: But Obj-C class has error parameter :-) Please, supply us with code snippet... What kind of object you try to save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of Firebase (6.x) requires at least Xcode 10.1.

This has been true since the App Store began requiring Xcode 10 in Spring 2019.

A workaround to use previous version of Xcode would be to update the Podfile to specify Firebase versions that released before that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul. Do you have any resources on how to install older versions of firebase using cocoa pods ?

Comment: See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod and https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase